# How can i detect that a thread not created by me is finished ? (to call mysql_thread_end)

Tags: mysql, multithreading, libmysql

**I have a problem with the design of mysql client library.**

MySQL requires that each thread that uses the MySQL API first call **mysql_thread_init()** 
and at the end call 
**mysql_thread_end().** 
If the thread fails to call 
mysql_thread_end(), 
then MySQL will block the main thread at program termination and wait for this threads to call 
mysql_thread_end(). 
If that doesn't happen, then it prints an error message to STDERR. Not a very user-friendly behavior.

now the problem is that i m inside an ISAPI dll, **it's not me who create the thread (nor destructing it)**, it's IIS that manage it.

How can i be warned then the thread will end to call **mysql_thread_end** ?

Comment: I believe if you are the one who called the init then you are the one responsible for calling end too. Does not really matter who created the thread.

Comment: no, it's really matter ! because i don't want to do mysql_thread_init and msql_thread_end for every query. it's because i use a connection pool ..